# What is the utility of this peanut-shaped ground facility?

Tags: launch, identify-this-object, launch-site, isro, launchpad

The following image is from GSLV-F11 GSAT-7A Mission:

[image]

Location: Second Launch Pad (SLP), Satish Dhawan Space Centre, Sriharikota, India.

*Please [click here](https://www.isro.gov.in/gslv-f11-gsat-7a-mission/gslv-f11-gsat-7a-mission-gallery) in case you want to see the image in ISRO's Website.*

In the bottom left corner of the image, there is a peanut-shaped building next to the water tower for the sound-suppression system, which is indicated by a red rectangle.

Another view of the peanut:

[image]

The peanut is on the right side, the middle portion of the image.

What is the use of this ground facility? Why is it peanut-shaped? Is that for storing rocket propellant*? What is the advantage of this shape? Are there any other launch sites with such structures?

---

*On examining the picture closely, the peanut is under construction, so I think it cannot be for storing propellants.

Comment: From Google maps this seems to be on the [second launch complex](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Satish+Dhawan+Space+Centre/@13.7204999,80.2299173,1013a,35y,47.12h/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x3a4da27eef264eaf:0xe9dec0ba1d50651f!8m2!3d13.7258653!4d80.2265545)  of the Satish Dhawan Space Centre (SDSC) in Sriharikota, but it's not in that photo.

Comment: This structure is quite old and has intrigued me as well for a while. Looking at old satellite images at 13.721944, 80.226111 it appears this structure came up between 2 September 2003 to 5 March 2004 which is before Second Launch Pad became operational. It can't be related to propellants.

Comment: @Ohsin, The launch took place on December 19, 2018.

Comment: @Intellex SLP was inaugurated on 4 May 2005 and became operational with PSLV-C6 launching from it next day. This peanut water tower like structure came up before it.

Comment: @Ohsin, I meant the images of the launch (above) were taken on December 19, 2018. I don't know when it was built but know for sure that it existed even in 2018.

Comment: an image search turned up no labeled images of this structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently it is an overhead tank (OHT) associated with fire suppression system of Second Launch Pad in Sriharikota. Learned about this from a [recent tender](https://old.reddit.com/r/ISRO/comments/i4ftrt/updated_layout_of_augmented_second_launch_pad/?) about upgrading fire suppression to meet safety requirements of Augmented Second Launch Pad project under which few new facilities will be added to SLP complex to serve future line of Kerolox based launch vehicle family of ISRO. Quoting from tender this structure is 42 meters high and with 300 cubic meter capacity to hold water.

> Existing OHT of 300 Cu. m

> 42 m staging height

> Existing system configuration:
> At present to meet the water requirements of fire protection system of SLP complex facilites,dedicated Fire water pump room (FPR) consisting of Nine pumps of 410 m^3/hr capacity each with 105m head are connected to Ground level reservoir (GLR) of capacity 2700m^3.
> **In addition to the above Two Nos. of Over head tanks (OHTs) of capacity 300 m^3 and 42m staging height each are also connected to the deluge system.**

[image: SLP dual tank OHT]

[Location of OHT](https://www.google.com/maps/place/13%C2%B043%2719.8%22N+80%C2%B013%2734.4%22E/@13.7221602,80.2240383,736m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d13.7221552!4d80.2262267)